# Passing several ByteStrings to C

Tags: c, haskell, bytestring

I have a C function that I want to expose to Haskell via FFI that takes three strings:

```
c_fun :: CString -> CString -> CString -> IO ()
```

How can I use `useAsCString` from `Data.ByteString` to pass 3 `ByteString`s from Haskell? I.e. I'm looking for a implementation of the following:

```
haskellFun :: ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString -> IO ()
```

`useAsCString` has type `ByteString -> (CString -> IO a) -> IO a`, so it's clear how to use it with a function that accepts one `CString` but I can't figure out how to put it together with three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```hs
useAsCStrings3
    :: (CString -> CString -> CString -> IO a)
    -> ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString
    -> IO a
useAsCStrings3 f a b c =
    useAsCString a (\a' ->
        useAsCString b (\b' ->
            useAsCString c (\c' ->
                f a' b' c'
            )
        )
    )
```

It type checks for me, and I've used similar techniques in the past when interoping with a C-library.  You could implement your `haskellFun` as

```
haskellFun = useAsCStrings3 c_fun
```

(note: I swapped the order of arguments to useAsCStrings3 during this edit, otherwise there isn't as pretty of an implementation for `haskellFun`)

Comment: Nice, seems straightforward.